# mdf file connection is not working properly

Tags: c#, sql-server, mdf

My *.mdf is in the App_Data folder, what is the correct connection string to connect to the database?
i tried this connection string but I am getting a connection error:

```
Connection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\College.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

Comment: Which exception do you get exactly? Are you using ASP.NET? If not, |DataDirectory| will not work (you can make it work using the trick shown here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html)

Comment: error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Comment: Yes i am using ASP.NET

Comment: Did you set DataDirectory somewhere explicitely? To trobleshoot the issue, you could get the directory where DataDirectoty points to using `(string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory")`.

Comment: Thank you so much guys,it is ok now

Comment: General typos and slight readability improvement